# Creating ArcMap where two parts of different imagery basemaps are visible at once?

Tags: arcmap, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps, swipe

```
I'm using ArcMap to create
backgrounds for a book of poetry 
where the backgrounds of poems
are satellite imagery.
```

I would like to have a section of my map be from a BW image and another from a color image, but I can only figure out how to view one basemap at a time.

Would I be able to dictate boundary between two the layers?

Comment: Have you looked at the Swipe tool?

Comment: wow. didn't even know about the image analysis window. thanks for the quick help! Is there a way to use the swipe tool in ways other than top-bottom/left-right? Also, how do you maintain the image at the swipe location? when i release the swipe tool it disappears. thanks again!

Comment: Swipe is just one way.  Clipping one or both rasters may be another.  If you try that and get stuck then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would use the [Swipe Layer tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/interactively-reveal-rasters-using-the-swipe-layer-tool.htm):

> The Swipe Layer tool is used to interactively reveal layers beneath
>   the layer being swiped. This tool makes it easy to see what is
>   underneath a particular layer without having to turn it off in the
>   table of contents.
>
> You can access the Swipe Layer tool from within the Image Analysis
>   window, where you interact with raster layers, and you can also access
>   it from the Effects toolbar, where you can interact with any layer in
>   the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished by clipping one background image to a polygon of your design in another shapefile, while excluding the other background image from the clip. You would be able to get artistic with the shape you clip to. Think of it like a mask in photoshop.

[https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm#:~:text=Right%2Dclick%20the%20data%20frame,Click%20the%20Specify%20Shape%20button](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm#:%7E:text=Right%2Dclick%20the%20data%20frame,Click%20the%20Specify%20Shape%20button).